# How to return rows with dates older than X years from today?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm writing a query in Postgres to return the avg. length of hospital stay for all patients older than 65 years ago. p.date_of_birth contains dates, like '2020-04-20'. I came up with the following WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    AVG(surgical_discharge_date - surgical_admission_date) AS avg_stay
FROM
    hosp.surgical_encounters as e
LEFT JOIN hosp.patients as p
    ON e.master_patient_id = p.master_patient_id
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE - p.date_of_birth > 23741.25
```

it returns a value that seems realistic although i'm not sure if it's correct. Does the query return indeed 65+-year-olds? (65 years -> 23741.25 days). Is there a better way to put such conditions, without the need to break it down into days? Thanks!

Comment: [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: @Cid like this:
```EXTRACT(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR from p.date_of_birth) > 65``` ? It seems to have returned the correct value

Comment: No, will return 65 too early. `EXTRACT(YEAR from '2022-01-01') - EXTRACT(YEAR from '2021-12-31')` will return 1 year, but it's only 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [INTERVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

```
select current_date - interval '1 year';
```

Which today 2022-09-06 returns

```
      ?column?
---------------------
 2021-09-06 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: how would this look like in the example above?

Comment: Replace the part after select in your where clause

Comment: OK. `WHERE p.date_of_birth < current_date - interval '65 year'` worked great, thank you.